# C++ vectors (instead of arrays)

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I am writing a lexer and I stored the keywords and reserved words in an array like below:

```
string keywords[20] = {

  "and",
  "or",
  "while",
  "not",
  "if",
  "read",
  "write",
  "set",
};
```

I found that I could use vectors as :

```
vector<string> keyword_list;
keyword_list.clear();

keyword_list.push_back("and");
keyword_list.push_back("or");
keyword_list.push_back("not");
```

However in this I need isKeyword method be modified for a vector and returns true or false .

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: _'However in this case how can the isKeyword method be modified for a vector '_ Yeah right! And what's the problem now?

Comment: Actually, when you know keywords at compile time, you don't need vectors. Static array and std::find and you are good to go.

Comment: @cubuspl42 you are saying to leave the array at it is and use find instead of the isKeyword method?

Comment: @user3599420 Not really. I'm just saying that this is not the case where one needs `std::vector`. Good old arrays will do better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

bool isKeyword( const std::string &s )
{
   return ( std::find( keyword_list.begin(), keyword_list.end(), s ) != keyword_list.end() );
}
```

If the vector would be sorted then you could use standard algorithm `std::binary_search`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

bool isKeyword( const std::string &s )
{
   return ( std::binary_search( keyword_list.begin(), keyword_list.end(), s ) );
}
```

Comment: infact I had tried the first example before I posted this but I am getting "find was not declared in this scope", what does that mean?

Comment: @user3599420 My example contains all what you need.